# Sortable table with its parent tr

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

Here is my table

```
<table class="sortable">
    <tr class="sort_tr">
     <td>
       <table>
    <tr><td>data sub1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>data sub2</td></tr>
        </table>
     </td>
   </tr class="sort_tr">
      <tr>
        <td>data2</td>
      </tr>
```

And my script for make this table sortable is as follows,

```
       <script>
        $(function() {
         $( ".sortable" ).sortable({items:'tr'});
        });
       </script>
```

I want to sort only the child tr of table with class "sortable".but now it is able to sort tr of child table.How to disable sorting of child?

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/shijin/BJ7K7/)

Answer (score 2):

Do you want this kind of functionality

then i used `:not()` selector for it

here i made the selection of all `<tr>` in `sortable` class except for the `table` and `tr` in the `sortable` class

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mayekarsaurabh/BJ7K7/1/)

---

**Edited:** 
Check this edited demo, is this what you want -->
[**Updated demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mayekarsaurabh/BJ7K7/2/)

Comment: do you know,is possible to make tr sortable with specific class?

Comment: @shin what do you mean ?

Comment: ,I updated my html structure,i want to make tr sortable only haveing class 'sort_tr'

Comment: sort_tr is already bind with droppable event,so that my code was not working.do you know how to work both together?.Thanks in advance

Comment: so u want to `sort_tr` under `sortable` to act as sortable and the rest as `droppable` ?